# Lanthanide and actinide contraction

Tags: atomic-physics

I am studying the lanthanide and actinide contractions and I have several questions:

1. What is the suspected cause of the contractions?
2. Assuming that the contractions end at $\mathrm{_{69}Tm}$ and $\mathrm{_{101}Md},$ respectively, what are the effects to those atoms other than smaller size?

Answer (score 1):

The Lanthanides and Actinides belong to resp. the first and second $f$ blocks.

> The informal chemical symbol Ln is used in general discussions of
>   lanthanide chemistry to refer to any lanthanide. All but one of the
>   lanthanides are f-block elements, corresponding to the filling of the
>   4f electron shell; depending on the source, either lanthanum or
>   lutetium is considered a d-block element, but is included due to its
>   chemical similarities with the other 14. All lanthanide elements
>   form trivalent cations, Ln3+, whose chemistry is largely determined by
>   the ionic radius, which decreases steadily from lanthanum to lutetium.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanide)

Instead of filling the outer orbitals, as happens with the $s$, $p$ and $d$ block elements, in the $\mathrm{Ln}$ group that filling occurs with the $4f$ orbitals (which are not the outer orbitals) The $4f$ are 'chosen' because of energy requirements.

This results in the lanthanide contraction.

> what are the effects to those atoms other than smaller size?

Not great, to be honest. The lanthanides are notorious for their close chemical resemblance. That's because their outer electron configurations are basically the same throughout the group.

In the case of the Actinides, it's the (inner) $5f$ orbital that's being filled.

The Actinides are less similar to each other than the Lanthanides because their massive electron clouds allow more deviation from 'manmade rules'

Comment: Note that about 10% of lanthanide contraction is due relativistic effects, especially on electrons in s orbitals.

Comment: Gert "In the case of the Actinides, it's the (inner) 5f orbital that's being filled."  The filling of that inner orbital leads me to think that there must be an effect on the nucleus.  Is there a known process or theory (either manmade i.e target or baryogenic) that could result in an Actinide being transmuted into an antimatter element with the same atomic number?

Comment: No. What goes on in the electron cloud has no bearing on the nucleus at all. The strong nuclear force is too... well, strong and too short range for the nucleus being affected by events 'too far away' (the electron cloud).

Comment: Is the following an exception to the electron cloud and the strong nuclear force?  The article doesn't seem to make a distinction on the type of atoms affected. " In the quantum mechanical model of the electron, there is a non-zero probability of finding the electron within the nucleus. During the internal conversion process, the wavefunction of an inner shell electron (usually an s electron) is said to penetrate the volume of the atomic nucleus."  (Wikipedia)

Comment: @Harry: the nuclear force has nothing with this. It doesn't even remotely reach into the electron cloud. It's is extremely short range.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration .This should make very useful reading for you.